# How to check if character is a whitespace?

Tags: java

I am trying to split the string `"   "` into 3 of `' '` character,
but when I try to do checking `if( curr_char == ' ')` or `if Character.isWhitespace(curr-char)` it does not read the curr_char as ' '. If the character is detecting as a whitespace then it should print:

> white space
>    white space
>    white space

but it does not.

```
package LexAnalyzer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LexAnalyzer {

    private String s;
    private char curr_char;
    private int i;  

    public LexAnalyzer(String s) {
        this.s = s;
        curr_char = s.charAt(0);
    }

    public void printTokenList() {
        while (i < s.length()) {
            //if the curr_char points somewhere in a string, keep go
            print_next_token();
        }
    }

    public void print_next_token() {

        if (i != 0) {
            curr_char = s.charAt(i);
        }

        //print "white space" if curr_char is whiteSpace
        if ( curr_char == ' ' || Character.isWhitespace(curr_char)) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", " white space");
        }

        i++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("   ");

        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("TEST CASE: "+ (i+1));
            System.out.println("Input String: " + input.get(i));
            System.out.println("");
            LexAnalyzer lex = new LexAnalyzer(input.get(i));
            System.out.println("Token List: ");
            lex.printTokenList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reported issue is currently not reproducable. Like Cody Walters, I also get the expected output "white space" three times. What does it print in your case? Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: okay Thank you though, I am not sure what is problem.

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println((int)curr_char + " -> " + (curr_char == ' ') + " -> " + Character.isWhitespace(curr_char));` before your check for a whitespace and tell use what it prints? It should be *"32 -> true -> true"*, but I wonder why it does on your machine.